# Source control makes sure my code is never lost, how do I make sure my users/orders database is never lost?

Tags: mysql, database-design

Everyone is recommending the use of git, automated tests, continuous integration, automated deployment and so on, to reduce human error during all stages of web development. 
I have yet to come across a clean, automated way of doing this for databases. 
Currently, I'm using the Symfony2 framework for PHP and doctrine to create/manage my users database in MySQL. How do I make sure that my users & orders databases will always remain safely backed up without manual intervention?

Comment: Questions about the management of a database should be asked on [dba.se]

Answer (score 3):

You can dump databases with a cron job, but your database schema should be under version control just like all the other code.

For MySQL, see [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html).

Copy or move the backup files to a safe place. (Or to two different safe places.) The database server is *not* a safe place.

Comment: Not just the schema should be under version control, but *migration scripts* to modify your schema from one version to the next, handling data modification as necessary. There are many tools for this.